# Google Sheets Formula - Convert time from 12 to 24 hour

Tags: google-sheets

Not sure where I am going wrong here, but I am trying to convert times in a Google Sheet from 12-hour format, e.g. 02:15:00 pm, to 24-hour format 14:15:00. I have tried several different formulas and/or selected the format from Googles formatting time options. Numerous sites provide this simple formula in Column D =TEXT(C4,"[hh]:mm:ss") but that won't convert.

[image: Sheet Image]

Please see the sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15ae7fjKiDFW5_38nn9MOWCzptqkEaM9AcOznGnkPFzI/edit?usp=sharing

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert your date/time text data to pure `date/time` value. Then apply any format you desire. Try-

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXT(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A3:A5,".","")),"HH:MM:SS"))
```

Or you can use cell formatting to display correct date/time format.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,
 TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A3:A," (.+)"),".",""))))
```

[image]

### Explanation

- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) the time and [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) the dots `"."` with nothing `"."`.
- set `(time_string)` of [`TIMEVALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en) function to the output of [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en).
- `ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,` to calculate only when the cells in `A3:A` is not empty